# Any good C++ library for displaying large bitmaps

Tags: c++, bitmap, sdk

I'm currently using MFC/GDI and Stingray to display bitmaps in my application and am looking for a better solution.  Specifically;

- Faster drawing speed - My current solution is slow, based on StretchDIBits
- Better rendering quality -  StretchDIBits rendering quality is awful when scaling a bitmap
- Support for rotated bitmaps
- Support for loading / saving in all popular formats
- Support for large bitmaps - I'm regularly using aerial photographs that are ~64mb as 12,000x12,000 jpegs.  GeoTIFF support would also be useful
- Compatible with MFC document/view, including printing (e.g. must be able render to a CDC)
- Access to source code is good but not necessary
- Easy to use / port existing GDI code

While free is always nice, I don't mind spending a reasonable amount on a decent library,  though no run time royalty costs.  Googling suggests the following;

- [CImg](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/)
- [Graphics Magick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/)
- [Lead Tools imaging SDK](http://www.leadtools.com/sdk/imaging.htm?linkid=top_menu)

Anyone got experience of these or can recommend an good alternative?

Comment: I see that you're scaling JPEGs over more than a factor of 8. In this case, you should have done the scaling at JPEG level, not bitmap. This is *WAY* faster. JPEG compresses blocks of 8x8 pixels using fourier components. The {0,0} component, explicitly stored is the average value. Hence it is bloody fast and fairly trivial to scale down a JPEG image by a factor of 8. E.g. you'd get a 1500*1500 bitmap out of a 12000*12000 pixel JPEG, and it's likely that your disk speed will be the limiting factor there.

Comment: @MSalters, good comment, and given that the command I'm using is StretchDIBits, I'm guessing that what your saying is true. All the more reason to adopt a different approach.

Answer (score 3):

GDI+ is available on any Windows machine since early XP.  It has codecs for all popular image formats, JPEG is included.  Very nice filters for high-quality image rescaling.  Unrestricted image rotation.  Draws to a CDC through the Graphics class.  Source code for the C++ wrappers are available in the SDK gdiplusXxx.h header files.  Speed is likely to be equivalent however, rendering is software based to ensure compatibility.

You can `#include <gdiplus.h>` and use the C++ wrappers directly.  The SDK docs [are here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533798%28VS.85%29.aspx). The CImage class is available in MFC, it doesn't expose all capabilities however.

Comment: +1 This is probably a good first step, as it should be a very easy port.  I've been meaning to swap from GDI to GDI+ for awhile, so now is probably time to bite the bullet.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's unlikely you'll find something that performs *faster* than GDI on windows since it has kernel-level support which is something open source solutions will not have.

You might want to also look into OpenGL or Direct2D/Direct3D since these too have direct access to the frame buffer. With 3D APIs, texture size would probably be an issue since most standards limit to something like 4096x4096.

Comment: I'm not convinced about the speed thing.  This may be true if I wasn't scaling the bitmaps, but StretchDIBits doesn't seem that fast at scaling and drawing a 4000x4000 pixel bitmap in say a 300x300 pixel box.  It also produces an awful result.  The following discussion on StretchDIBits speed is also interesting http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=344785

Comment: Moving the whole lot OpenGL is certainly worth considering, though would possible involve a lot of work and pose problems on the printing side of things.

Comment: StretchDIBits does a simple nearest neighbor scaling. For some applications that is exactly what you want and nothing else. (for instance for an image editor zoom)

Answer (score 2):

I have used [CxImage](http://www.xdp.it/cximage.htm) in the past which is one to add to your evaluation list.